# Does PHP timeout occurs when scheduling the job with wp_schedule event

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, scheduled-tasks

I had scheduled a job using `wp_schedule event`. Now before going further I just wanted to make sure that whether or not PHP timeout issue occurs for `wp_schedule event` because my script will take a lot of time to complete.

Comment: are you using `wp schedule event`? and what do you mean by the `timeout` issue here? are you afraid that the job will not be executed after your specified timeout?

Comment: No, with timeout I meant the PHP execution time like my script is going to run for at least 30 minutes.

Comment: are using `wp schedule event` ?? what is `wp_schedule` where did you get this ?

Comment: Yes, it's `wp schedule event` sorry I thought both are same things